# How can I execute additional commands after changes detected by `compass watch`?

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass, compass

I've executed `compass watch` in a [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) project.

It works great, my assets are compiled as I make settings changes.

However, I'd like to also run additional a few `grunt` commands each time I make changes.

How can I add to the actions that compass performs when changes are detected?

Specifically, I'd like to run two commands from another directory.

This is what I've got:

```
cd /dir_foundation/
bundle exec compasss watch
```

After each change, I want it to also call:

```
grunt sass:dist
grunt cssmin
```

These grunt tasks are defined in a gruntfile that is 2 directories "up" from the `/dir_foundation/` where the `compass watch` command is monitoring changes.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer.

http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/#callbacks

This is what I added to my config.rb file:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |file|
  system('../../../compile.bat')
end
```

Where "compile.bat" contains:

```
grunt sass:dist
grunt cssmin
```